Join two df and cut second df field by first df field condition during join?
I have two df  -
first contains start and end position, like
id start end 

1  4     8

2  2     6

2  5     7


And second df with id-string
id string

1   my beautiful data

2   lorem ipsum

Join "as is" and then cut string to needed positions - fails out of memory.
First df has about 1kk entries, and second - about 10 entries, but every string is about 100Mb
So i am thinking if it is possible to cut string during join, and then every string will be few chars - and it's acceptable size.
Result should be like:
id start end seq
1  | 4   |  8  | beaut

2  | 2   |  6  | orem i

2  | 5   | 7   | m i



Thanks a lot!
UPD:
Currently i just do join 1-to-1, and then get substring like
df1 = df1.join(df2, "id") 

df1.withColumn("substring" df1['string'].substr(df1.start, df1.end))).show() 

But join fails with OOM, here is Optimized physical plan (i tried broadcast, repartition), but anyway such size for intermediate result is unacceptable. Separetly this dfs are shown and processed without errors:
exonsDF = exons_raw.join(dnaDF, "seq_region_id").explain("cost")
   == Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [seq_region_id#63L, exon_id#62L, seq_region_start#64L, seq_region_end#65L, seq_region_strand#66, phase#67, end_phase#68, is_current#69, is_constitutive#70, stable_id#71, version#72, created_date#73, modified_date#74, transcript_id#75L, rank#76, sequence#148], Statistics(sizeInBytes=12.3 PiB)
+- Join Inner, (seq_region_id#63L = cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=14.4 PiB)
   :- Repartition 10, true, Statistics(sizeInBytes=13.6 MiB)
   :  +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#63L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=13.6 MiB)
   :     +- Relation [exon_id#62L,seq_region_id#63L,seq_region_start#64L,seq_region_end#65L,seq_region_strand#66,phase#67,end_phase#68,is_current#69,is_constitutive#70,stable_id#71,version#72,created_date#73,modified_date#74,transcript_id#75L,rank#76] orc, Statistics(sizeInBytes=13.6 MiB)
   +- Repartition 10000, true, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1083.8 MiB)
      +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#147), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1083.8 MiB)
         +- Relation [seq_region_id#147,sequence#148] orc, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1083.8 MiB)

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [seq_region_id#63L, exon_id#62L, seq_region_start#64L, seq_region_end#65L, seq_region_strand#66, phase#67, end_phase#68, is_current#69, is_constitutive#70, stable_id#71, version#72, created_date#73, modified_date#74, transcript_id#75L, rank#76, sequence#148]
   +- SortMergeJoin [seq_region_id#63L], [cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint)], Inner
      :- Sort [seq_region_id#63L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(seq_region_id#63L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=335]
      :     +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [plan_id=330]
      :        +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#63L)
      :           +- FileScan orc [exon_id#62L,seq_region_id#63L,seq_region_start#64L,seq_region_end#65L,seq_region_strand#66,phase#67,end_phase#68,is_current#69,is_constitutive#70,stable_id#71,version#72,created_date#73,modified_date#74,transcript_id#75L,rank#76] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(seq_region_id#63L)], Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/nfs/production/flicek/ensembl/infrastructure/mira/19tmp/exons], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(seq_region_id)], ReadSchema: struct<exon_id:bigint,seq_region_id:bigint,seq_region_start:bigint,seq_region_end:bigint,seq_regi...
      +- Sort [cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint), 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=336]
            +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10000), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [plan_id=331]
               +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#147)
                  +- FileScan orc [seq_region_id#147,sequence#148] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(seq_region_id#147)], Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/nfs/production/flicek/ensembl/infrastructure/mira/6tmp/sequence], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(seq_region_id)], ReadSchema: struct<seq_region_id:string,sequence:string>



UPD2 - with new plan

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [seq_region_id#63L, exon_id#62L, seq_region_start#64L, seq_region_end#65L, seq_region_strand#66, phase#67, end_phase#68, is_current#69, is_constitutive#70, stable_id#71, version#72, created_date#73, modified_date#74, transcript_id#75L, rank#76, sequence#148], Statistics(sizeInBytes=12.3 PiB)
+- Join Inner, (seq_region_id#63L = cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=14.4 PiB)
   :- RepartitionByExpression [seq_region_id#63L], Statistics(sizeInBytes=13.6 MiB)
   :  +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#63L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=13.6 MiB)
   :     +- Relation [exon_id#62L,seq_region_id#63L,seq_region_start#64L,seq_region_end#65L,seq_region_strand#66,phase#67,end_phase#68,is_current#69,is_constitutive#70,stable_id#71,version#72,created_date#73,modified_date#74,transcript_id#75L,rank#76] orc, Statistics(sizeInBytes=13.6 MiB)
   +- RepartitionByExpression [cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint)], Statistics(sizeInBytes=1083.8 MiB)
      +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#147), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1083.8 MiB)
         +- Relation [seq_region_id#147,sequence#148] orc, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1083.8 MiB)

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [seq_region_id#63L, exon_id#62L, seq_region_start#64L, seq_region_end#65L, seq_region_strand#66, phase#67, end_phase#68, is_current#69, is_constitutive#70, stable_id#71, version#72, created_date#73, modified_date#74, transcript_id#75L, rank#76, sequence#148]
   +- SortMergeJoin [seq_region_id#63L], [cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint)], Inner
      :- Sort [seq_region_id#63L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(seq_region_id#63L, 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, [plan_id=330]
      :     +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#63L)
      :        +- FileScan orc [exon_id#62L,seq_region_id#63L,seq_region_start#64L,seq_region_end#65L,seq_region_strand#66,phase#67,end_phase#68,is_current#69,is_constitutive#70,stable_id#71,version#72,created_date#73,modified_date#74,transcript_id#75L,rank#76] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(seq_region_id#63L)], Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/nfs/production/flicek/ensembl/infrastructure/mira/0tmp/exons], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(seq_region_id)], ReadSchema: struct<exon_id:bigint,seq_region_id:bigint,seq_region_start:bigint,seq_region_end:bigint,seq_regi...
      +- Sort [cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint), 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, [plan_id=331]
            +- Filter isnotnull(seq_region_id#147)
               +- FileScan orc [seq_region_id#147,sequence#148] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(seq_region_id#147)], Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/nfs/production/flicek/ensembl/infrastructure/mira/0tmp/sequence], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(seq_region_id)], ReadSchema: struct<seq_region_id:string,sequence:string>


please show what are you currently using and the machines memory size.

@Chris 40g of memory - single drive usage.  sorry, first df is 1kk , not 100k . So i dont't think it's ever good idea to merge to every row line about 100M, if we really need only few characters from it

that's useful, please show the sql / code you are using

@Chris currently i have no good idea,
just
df1 = df1.jon(df2, "id")
df1.with column("substring" df1['string'].substr(df1.start, df1.end))).show()
and it fails on join with Java Heap OOM

which spark version and can you please post the query plan?

@Chris please see UPD in question, it estimates join size in Ptb which is terrible

what is the spark version used?  I'd guess this as a 3.5 version without any further information but can you also confirm if you are the using reparition(100) and repartition(1000) in your code?

@Chris yes to everything. I am using repartitions - and i tried many option - with repartition, without, different values or repartition from 4 to 1000, broadcast ... it didn't make any difference

Rather than repartitioning by a number, attempt to do so through the  seq_region_id field:
exon = exon.repartition(exon['seq_region_id'])
sequence = sequence.repartition(sequence['seq_region_id'].cast("bigint"))

The cast is necessary as

cast(seq_region_id#147 as bigint)

is required from sequence which has string, exon has bigint on disk.  That may be on purpose but given the names and this example it looks like a mistake, this too would speed things up to correct on disk.
Given 3.5 usage the sorted merge join is definitely the fastest / most efficient way to handle this and spark will choose this for you.
Lastly make sure to drop "sequence" after the substring operation.  This will let spark know it's not required in the final output and also stands a chance of being lower memory usage.

Thanks a lot! I haven't tried yet - but it's all the best that can be done, for sure. Will respond here after try as well

For now - it doesn't fail with the oom which usually happened after 5 min, but still running (like 8 hours already on 30G of memory for driver, single mode). Hopefully will be complete fine.

could you add the new query plan after that change?   Although that might just be as good as it gets, you could also try to use group by (for seq_region_id and sequence) and collect_set for the offsets, then use array_transform.

Still didn't finished, was interrupted accidentally, and pls see update with new plan - it looks the same for me, in Pit - but definitely runs different

And also explain() desn't include drop("sequence") only join

are you running the "only join" or after drop?  Eitherway worth trying the group by approach.

While waiting - i ended up with another approach - in a loop: read one seq from db, filter exons that has that seq_id - and apply udf() on exons, while sequence - is just broadcasted variable (non spark) passed to that udf. At the iteration end - union exons bunch with result. Finished all run in about 10 min. Yes, that loop is not parallel run and forever single-node - but speed is unbeatable
